# Chrome extension: how to dock extension's html page to current web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a chrome extension which docks a new panel to the bottom of current web page. The GUI should be something like Developer tools.

I tried to inject an iframe to web page like this:

```
$('body').append(
    '<iframe src="'
    + chrome.extension.getURL('panel.html')
    + '" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; bottom: 0px; height: 300px; display: block;"></iframe>');
```

The iframe can be seen, but it covers the content of the main page.
How can I solve the problem?  Hope someone can give me some suggestions or simple examples...

Comment: The code in your question is jQuery, which suggests that you've already included jQuery in your extension. Can you show the relevant contents of the `manifest.json` file, and the other relevant code? A screenshot to elaborate your problem is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with this you're not adjusting the underlying page so that the bottom 300px of the page isn't covered up from your panel. Here is some javascript to bump up the bottom of the page 300px:

```
var html = document.documentElement;
//make sure <html> to the top of the page:
html.style.position = 'relative';
html.style.top = '0px';

window.onresize = function resizeFunc(){
  html.style.height = (window.innerHeight - 300) + 'px';
};
window.onresize();
```

Also, instead of just appending to the body like this: `$('body').append(`, I suggest using `document.documentElement` instead of `body`, and even using vanilla javascript for something so basic, this would look like:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style = '<your style code above>';
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('panel.html');
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
```

I think this will solve your problem... not sure if your page has something unique that's causing an error

Comment: With your solution, the injected iframe will not cover the content of the main web page, but it cannot be fixed at the bottom of the browser window. But I want both. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If it's not fixed at the bottom of the browser window, how do you want it to be positioned?